# Android - Very basic right swipe detect

Tags: android

I'm trying to code a stopwatch which resets itself when you swipe right on the touchscreen. I've had a look round here and on Google, and I can't find anything which explains how this would be done in very simplistic terms - I think it would be some kind of gesture detector, but none of the explanations have been particularly clear on how I would implement this.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `on the touchscreen`!! which screen? the `Home Screen` or `your app screen`?

Comment: The app screen, I would imagine.

Comment: Generally speaking you need to implement a GestureDetector and in the onSwipe() method call your reset method, using the parameters given by onSwype to check the direction of swype. I think that's right, could be something completely different though, I just said what I remember from the one time I had to detect sypw.

Comment: That's precisely the problem - what is a GestureDetector? How do I implement it? What is the "onSwipe()" method?

Comment: Subclass [GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html) and override `onFling()` to detect the swipe. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection